# How to write Execute AS Script in Stored Procedure in Azure Synapse Dedicated Pool?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, azure-synapse, execute-as

I am trying to create a Stored Procedure in Azure Synapse Dedicated Pool, but I am facing an error.
I don't know much about Transact-SQL and Synapse limitations, so I am unable to debug the real issue here.
This Stored Procedure is part of [AdventureWorks2019](https://github.com/Microsoft/sql-server-samples/releases/tag/adventureworks) sample database by Microsoft, and the name of the stored procedure is **HumanResources.uspUpdateEmployeeLogin**.

Create Script of SP in SSMS is:

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO


CREATE PROCEDURE [HumanResources].[uspUpdateEmployeeLogin]
    @BusinessEntityID [int], 
    @OrganizationNode [hierarchyid],
    @LoginID [nvarchar](256),
    @JobTitle [nvarchar](50),
    @HireDate [datetime],
    @CurrentFlag [dbo].[Flag]
WITH EXECUTE AS CALLER
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    BEGIN TRY
        UPDATE [HumanResources].[Employee] 
        SET [OrganizationNode] = @OrganizationNode 
            ,[LoginID] = @LoginID 
            ,[JobTitle] = @JobTitle 
            ,[HireDate] = @HireDate 
            ,[CurrentFlag] = @CurrentFlag 
        WHERE [BusinessEntityID] = @BusinessEntityID;
    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH
        EXECUTE [dbo].[uspLogError];
    END CATCH;
END;
GO
```

I am trying to run this code with some changes in data types that aren't supported in synapse.
SQL Script in Synapse:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [HumanResources].[uspUpdateEmployeeLogin]
    @BusinessEntityID [int], 
    @OrganizationNode [nvarchar](100),
    @LoginID [nvarchar](256),
    @JobTitle [nvarchar](50),
    @HireDate [datetime],
    @CurrentFlag [bit]


WITH EXECUTE AS CALLER
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    BEGIN TRY
        UPDATE [HumanResources].[Employee] 
        SET [OrganizationNode] = @OrganizationNode 
            ,[LoginID] = @LoginID 
            ,[JobTitle] = @JobTitle 
            ,[HireDate] = @HireDate 
            ,[CurrentFlag] = @CurrentFlag 
        WHERE [BusinessEntityID] = @BusinessEntityID;
    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH
        EXECUTE [dbo].[uspLogError];
    END CATCH;
END;
```

The error that I am getting is:

```
Parse error at line: 10, column: 1: Incorrect syntax near 'WITH'.
```

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Synapse doesn't support the `WITH` clause there (as noted by its exclusion in the [syntax](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-procedure-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16#code-try-3)) Do you need to use `WITH EXECUTE AS CALLER`? Have you tried simply removing the clause?

Comment: @Larnu I tried using without `WITH EXECUTE AS CALLER` and it worked. Thanks for the help. But can you tell me what is the purpose of that clause and what affect will it have if we don't keep it?

Comment: @Larnu As your solution worked, please convert it into answer to help other community members.

Answer (score 0):

Synapse doesn't support the WITH clause there (as noted by its exclusion in the syntax) Do you need to use WITH EXECUTE AS CALLER? Have you tried simply removing the clause?

EXECUTE AS CALLER is the default for SQL Server stored procedures anyway, and Synapse doesn't support any other style.

```
CREATE { PROC | PROCEDURE } [ schema_name.] procedure_name
    [ { @parameter data_type } [ OUT | OUTPUT ] ] [ ,...n ]
AS
{
  [ BEGIN ] sql_statement [;][ ,...n ] [ END ]
}
[;]
```

[CREATE PROCEDURE - Synapse Analytics](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-procedure-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16)